# How to execute a class in other class using splash.java

Tags: java, json

I have this code in main java

```
    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();
}
```

...

How to execute that in splash.java?
Splash is splashscreen ...and main.java is json reader that i want to execute

THE MAIN PURPOSE IS ...TO EXECUTE SOME METHODE Of MAINACTIVITy in SplashscreemActivity :(

Comment: Hey there, your question needs to be fleshed out more. Right now it's not clear what splash.java is or really what problem you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add parenthesis

```
 (new GetContacts()).execute();
```

Comment: Hey.  That is not answer